# How to use folding cell library?

Tags: android

I downloaded a project from github.

Basically what my need is that, I want to make user click on any item in listview, and below that , some sort of dialog or list opens, which allows user to perform some action like download or anything.. SO Kindly Suggest some ways..

Link for same library is https://github.com/Ramotion/folding-cell-android

Answer (score 0):

folding cell library is not for handling dialogues.
What you need is to handle click actions on list item using the click listeners

for example:

```
listViewItem.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                    long id) {
                //this starts a new activity
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SendMessage.class);
                String message = "abc";
                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```